# C++ Win32 GetDC and when to ReleaseDC

Tags: c++, winapi

In my program (game), I made the GetDC() call and saved the DC as a global. I was figuring I could just ReleaseDC() at the end of the program.

Currently I am having trouble as some things are not drawing correct. I use the DC with various functions, and in a timer.

Is that what could be causing the issue?

(the size of the program is too much to change everything to see if it will or will not help...)

EDIT:
The only one I save globably (and set it after the windows created) is the

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd)
```

Then, whenever I need to do something:

```
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
// everything
DeleteDC(hdcMem)
```

Then at the end of the program:

```
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
```

Is it possible that with all the drawing and object selection going on in various places of the code is causing these "semi-rare" problems?

Also, forgot to note, there are no GDI leaks anywhere.

Comment: Unless you're using a dedicated compatible DC for something like background bitmap manipulation and later using it as a blt-src to dump to window or client dc (and even there, its questionable whether you still *need* to do this) I wouldn't advise hanging on to them forever.

Comment: The only one I save globably is the 

HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd)

Then, when I need to do something: 

HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
// everything
DeleteDC(hdcMem)

Then at the end of the program:

ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

Is it possible that with all the drawing and object selection going on in various places of the code is causing these "semi-rare" problems?

Also, forgot to note, there are no GDI leaks anywhere.

Comment: Given everything you just described I'd use a compatibleDC based on an init-setup clientDC (which you release afterward), do all your data manipulation on the compatible-dc and a selected bitmap you created. Then to update your window either invalidate the region you desire to repaint and let a *very* simple WM_PAINT handler blast bits from your DC to the paint-dc, or in an i-need-this-updated-now moment, invalidate+updatewindow. Try and opt for the former, as Windows will optimize the update region if you hit it with multiple invalidates. try not to draw outside a paint message if possible.

Comment: Instead of describing a problem, you should supply a complete program that illustrates it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't store HDC for a long time.

And in general you don't need to do so. When you need to draw something you call `InvalidateRect(HWND, rc)` and when it is possible OS will send you WM_PAINT where you do painting.

In short: avoid drawing outside of WM_PAINT.